# IronPdf ignores Bootstrap column grids when creating PDF from HTML

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, pdf

For my example I have defined a simple page with a jumbotron and 2 columns, each with a distinct header and background-color. When viewing the HTML template within the browser you see the 2 column layout with Jumbotron as expected. When Viewing the pdf created by IronPdf the columns collapse into a single column layout with each div stacked and full width.

I have followed the example provided by IronPDF https://ironpdf.com/docs/questions/html-to-pdf-responsive-css/

Project demonstrating the issue is found here:
https://github.com/crumdev/IronPdfExample

I expect the output of the PDF to reflect what is shown in the browser as I need the column formatting to work in order to create the PDF layout with multi-column layouts I need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I received a response back from IronPdf:

> I had my engineer take a look into this and currently bootstrap isn't fully compatible with IronPDF. This is something we already have scheduled out to work on for our next builds later this year. I have it logged and will keep you up to date when I we have been able to resolve this. Thanks for your patience.

Comment: Use tables for the time being.

Comment: As per comment below. IronPDF will work with BootStrap 4.0.0 but not 4.3.1

Comment: in case someone wonders if IronPDF works with a more recent version. NO -> not working with 4.5.3 -> 4.0.0 works well.

Comment: Iron pdf seem to ignore w3.css col grid as well.

Answer (score 1):

I'm on the same situation, but works for me with the bootstrap version 4.0.0 and following the below code:

NOTE: if you can't see some columns, try to organize your col div inside each row

```
            HtmlToPdf Renderer = new HtmlToPdf();

            Renderer.PrintOptions.SetCustomPaperSizeInInches(8.5, 11);

            Renderer.PrintOptions.PaperOrientation = PdfPrintOptions.PdfPaperOrientation.Portrait;

            Renderer.PrintOptions.Title = "My PDF Document Name";

            Renderer.PrintOptions.RenderDelay = 50; //ms

            Renderer.PrintOptions.CssMediaType = PdfPrintOptions.PdfCssMediaType.Screen;

            Renderer.PrintOptions.DPI = 300;

            Renderer.PrintOptions.FitToPaperWidth = true;

            Renderer.PrintOptions.JpegQuality = 80;

            Renderer.PrintOptions.GrayScale = false;

            Renderer.PrintOptions.FitToPaperWidth = true;

            Renderer.PrintOptions.InputEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;

            Renderer.PrintOptions.Zoom = 100;

            Renderer.PrintOptions.ViewPortWidth = 1280;

            Renderer.PrintOptions.CreatePdfFormsFromHtml = true;

            Renderer.PrintOptions.CustomCssUrl = new Uri("https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.css");

            Renderer.PrintOptions.MarginTop = 10;  //millimeters
            Renderer.PrintOptions.MarginLeft = 10;  //millimeters
            Renderer.PrintOptions.MarginRight = 10;  //millimeters
            Renderer.PrintOptions.MarginBottom = 10;  //millimeters
            Renderer.PrintOptions.FirstPageNumber = 1;

            Renderer.RenderHtmlAsPdf(html).SaveAs(fileName);
```

Comment: Confirmed. IronPDF will work with BootStrap 4.0.0 but not with 4.3.1